# fgets returning error for FILE returned by popen

Tags: c, popen, fgets

I'm trying to execute a command line from my C code, but when I get to the fgets() function, I got a NULL error.

```
void executeCommand(char* cmd, char* output) {
    FILE *fcommand;
    char command_result[1000];
    fcommand = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fcommand == NULL) {
        printf("Fail: %s\n", cmd);
    } else {
        if (fgets(command_result, (sizeof(command_result)-1), fcommand) == NULL)
             printf("Error !");
        strcpy(output, command_result);
    }
    pclose(fcommand);
}
```

And my command is:

```
java -jar <parameters>
```

Why do I have a NULL result from fgets, despite that when I try to execute the same command in a terminal, it works as expected.

Comment: what do you get when calling `feof(fcommand)` and `ferror(fcommand)` after the `fgets` call fails ?

Comment: 1 for feof(fcommand) and 0 for ferror(fcommand)

Answer (score 4):

> fgets()  reads  in  at  most one less than size characters from stream 
>   and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an 
>   EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.

In short, the `popen()` is doing a `fork()` and you're trying to read from the pipe before the program evoked by `cmd` has produced output, therefor there is no data on the pipe and the first read on the pipe will return `EOF`, so `fgets()` returns without getting data. You either need to sleep, do a poll or do a blocking read.

Comment: a sleep? where? between the popen and the fgets ?

Comment: Yes... but a sleep is the worst solution because it is either (a) at risk of waking up before the output is ready or (b) keeping the user waiting long after the output was ready. The best answer is to do a blocking read on the pipe.

Comment: Are you sure? My understanding is that the read would block until there is data in the pipe. And the read will only return EOF when the other program closes its end of the pipe. I thought that was the whole point of pipes? I could be wrong though. For the original question. I suspect the exec is failing. Does you program have the same environment as the command line? No messing with path etc?

Comment: fgets() is a non-blocking read... regardless of the stream it is reading from.

Comment: @Sodved yeah it works perfectly in another standalone c file, even on a terminal.

Comment: @KScottPiel No the sleep didn't work, actually popen returns a success return code, so there is no trouble with reading the command and executing it. The blocking read either didn't work.