# Can't understand why this causes an error

Tags: c, linux, popen, fgets

I have a large directory of music which is listed in a file called `op`.  I have been able to build a command which will randomly pick a song from the `op` file using some creative math with the nanosecond output from the date command.  It works fine from the command line:

```
sed -n $((10#$(date +%N)%$(wc -l /shared/southpark/music/op|cut -d ' ' -f 1)))p /shared/southpark/music/op
```

I want to include this command in a c program and read the line in with popen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char command[201];
        char buf[501];
        FILE *fp;

        strcpy(command, "sed -n $((10#$(date +%N)%$(wc -l /shared/southpark/music/op|cut -d ' ' -f 1)))p /shared/southpark/music/op");

        if((fp = popen(command, "r")) == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "music_player: popen failed\n");
                return(1);
        }

        if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "music_player: fgets failed\n");
                return(1);
        }

        printf("%s\n", buf);
        pclose(fp);
        return(0);
}
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "10#271445839%2278"
music_player: fgets failed
```

How can I do this?  I'm not understanding the error message.

Comment: Think this might be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882799/fgets-returning-error-for-file-returned-by-popen

Comment: Are you aware of the `$RANDOM` variable, or the `sort -R` command?

Comment: Wait, why are you calling the shell if you're writing C?

Comment: @o11c - why should he not call the shell from a C program?

Comment: @Cyclone because most shell functionality is trivially implemented in C without the overhead of a subprocess.

Comment: @o11c - Yes, but I don't think the above `sed` command is that easy to implement from scratch. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and failing with both of nneonneo's options, I had to resort to placing the command in a bash script file and then I popen'ed the script.  It gives me the desired results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char command[201];
        char buf[501];
        FILE *fp;

        strcpy(command, "/dea/testing/popen/get_file");

        if((fp = popen(command, "r")) == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "music_player: popen failed\n");
                return(1);
        }

        if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) == NULL)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "music_player: fgets failed\n");
                return(1);
        }

        printf("%s", buf);
        pclose(fp);
        return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`popen` executes your command using

```
/bin/sh -c "command"
```

and your `sh` doesn't understand the `10#` base-conversion prefix. You've been running the command in `bash` previously.

To fix, you have two options:

1. Discard the unnecessary `10#` prefix (it is the default) for `sh` compatibility
2. Use `bash`:

   ```
   popen("bash -c 'command'", ...)
   ```

Comment: I have to use the decimal conversion, because the nanosecond option of date will include leading zeros which was messing with the earlier tries.

Comment: And changing the command to `strcpy(command, "bash -c \"sed -n $((10#$(date +%N)%$(wc -l /shared/southpark/music/op|cut -d ' ' -f 1)))p /shared/southpark/music/op\"");` created the same error as above.

Comment: Instead of using `date +%N`, then, consider using `(${RANDOM}<<15) + ${RANDOM}`, which uses `bash`'s built-in random number generator.